# Connect php with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html

I'm building a simple user login page when I put in my username and password nothing happens, it seems like its not connected to the database

here's my html code with some CSS and my php code that is below this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Intacs Login</title>
    <!-- inner css -->
        <style>  
          #login_logo {
              margin: 15px 10px 10px 0;
              display: block;

            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;

          }  
          .container{
              background-color: white;
              border-radius: 30px;
              border-color: lightgray;
              border-style:outset;
              width: 320px;
              margin-top: 30px;
              margin:auto;
              padding-top: 50px;
              padding-bottom: 50px;






      }

          #login_table{
              margin-top: auto;
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right: auto;
          }
          #login_remember{

              text-align: center;
          }


        </style>

  </head>
  <body>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- HTML code -->
    <div class="container">
        <div id="login_form">
            <div id="login_block">
            <img id="login_logo" src="img/Intacs Master Logo.jpg" 
             width="187" height="63"> <!--div container-->
        </div>
    </div>

   <table id="login_table" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <form method="post" action="connect.php"> <!--form to connect to php file called connect.php -->
                <th>Username:&nbsp;</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="usernamefield" class="loginfield" validate="/^[a-z0-9_]{2,}$/i" valmsg="Please enter a valid username." value="" size="14" maxlength="32">   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Password:&nbsp;</th>
                <td nowrap="nowrap">
                    <input type="password" name="password" 
       id="passwordfield" class="loginfield" validate="/^[^\s]{4,}$/" 
          valmsg="Please enter a valid password." value="" size="14" 
              maxlength="32">
                </td>

                </form>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
   <div id="login_remember"><input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me</div>
   <br />
   <center><input type="submit" value="Submit"></center>
  </body>

</html>

<?php
function Db() {
    $host = "localhost:8888";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "intacslogin";
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);

    if(!$conn){
        die("Could not connect");
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $uid = trim ($_POST['username']);
    $pwd = trim($_POST['password']);

    if($uid ==""){
        $err[] = "Username is missing";
    } else if($pwd == ""){
        $err[] = "Password is missing";
    } else{
        $db = Db();
        $uid = $db->real_escape_string($uid);
        $pwd = $db->real_escape_string($pwd);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE username = '$uid'
        and password = '$pwd'";
        $result = $db->query($sql);


    }
}

?>
```

Please Help thanks and happy coding thanks for your help.
Its a small personal project

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a database, it's a php application to access a MySQL database.

Comment: Db() function returns nothing means $db variable is useless.

Comment: I misread it the first time, make sure you format your code and properly indent to make your code more readable.

Comment: have your Db() function return the connection so it can be used for the query: `function Db() { ... if(!$conn) { die("Could not connect"); } else { return $conn; } }` and then your $db (the connection) can be used for the `$result = $db->query($sql);`

Comment: You have no input with name "login". So the `if(isset($_POST['login'])){...}` does not "work". Bring PHP at top to use the PHP vars in html. Close "container" div. The `form` tags (opening and closing tag) can only reside inside a `td` or a `th` tag. Never inside a `tr` tag. Move your `form` tags outside of the table. Bring checkbox in a table row with `colspan="2"`. The same for the button. The attributes `cellspacing`, `cellpadding`, `border` are not supported in HTML5. So replace them with css rules: `border-collapse: ...; border:...` for the table, `padding:...` for the `th` and `td`.

Comment: Read [this](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli), [this](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) & [this](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting) for error handling/reporting. Use _prepared statements_ for the db related operations to avoid eventual mysql injection. Good luck.

Comment: i'll try that thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//THIS FUNCTION SHOULD RETURN A CONNECTION TO BE USED IN A QUERY
function Db() {
    $host = "localhost:8888";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "intacslogin";
//MAKE SURE U CONFIRM A SUCCESSFULL CONNECTION LIKE SO
    if ($conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db)) {
    return $conn;
}else {
return false;
}


    //if(!$conn){
      //  die("Could not connect");
    //}
}

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $uid = trim ($_POST['username']);
    $pwd = trim($_POST['password']);

    if($uid ==""){
        $err[] = "Username is missing";
    } else if($pwd == ""){
        $err[] = "Password is missing";
    } else{

    if (!$conn) {
        //you can die() becouse it returned false  
    }else {
        //proced when we a valid connection
        //dont use $db use $conn
        $uid = $conn->real_escape_string($uid);
        $pwd = $conn->real_escape_string($pwd);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE username = '$uid'
        and password = '$pwd'";

        $result = $conn->query($sql); 
}


    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I copied your code and the login still does not work

Comment: no error its just pushing a new page, but I'll keep trying